# Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class (ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

Good morning

I'm developing a REST API with Java 8, Spring 5.3.29 and Spring Boot 2.7.14 and I'm having the next issue when I try to launch the application on a Tomcat 9 server in Eclipse:

```
GRAVE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4936)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:922)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:157)
    ... 29 more
```

When I debug to stop on SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:157, which is:

```
initializers.add((WebApplicationInitializer)
                                ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(waiClass).newInstance());
```

The waiClass is: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>es.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Description</description>
    <properties>
        <spring-framework.version>5.3.29</spring-framework.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- SPRING BOOT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JAXB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>pid</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is my Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

What can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Apache CXF was exporting Spring Core 3.0.7 into WEB-INF/lib folder of Tomcat server, and was overriding Spring Core 5.3.29, which was configured on pom.xml and contains the ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor method.

The solution is to not export Apache CXF libraries into WEB-INF/lib. So:

Right click on Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Apache CXF, remove the option that exports Apache CXF library into WEB-INF/lib.

See ya!